# get top 20 google results c# api

Tags: c#, google-api

I've been trying to write something similar to this but without any success so I was wondering if there is any google API or any other "function" which would allow me to do the following

```
List<string> GetTop20Links (string keyword)
{
//code to download and return top 20 results (links) in List<string> format
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer to use [Google API for .NET](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-for-dotnet/).

Comment: Far as I know you cant get result from search engine BUT you can only search your site

Comment: Great! Got it to work in one minute. Too bad I didn't find it :-)

Comment: @sdasfsa: No, it seems to give genuine results. The URL needed to construct the search client is just used as a referrer. You can leave it blank and you don't even need an API key (they will probably limit the number of requests though)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can determine from google's blogs, there once was (and maybe is still operational) a SOAP webservice that let you query structured search results. But you need a so called API key for the query and they don't give them out any more. The successor to this service was claimed to be the AJAX search API, but I cannot find any current reference to it.

On the [google API page](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/more/#google-search) there is a custom search service, but you have to give a specific set of websites that the search includes and you either need to show the ads along with the results or pay some fee for the usage.

You see, it's not in google's interest to let somebody easily query their search engine and then just use the results for whatever purpose. They are making money through the ads, that's their business model.

So if you want to realize that function you would have to turn to html-scraping which is ugly at best, tends to break often and is difficult to get right.

BTW: You *can* do that quite easily with bing. There is a link to the Bing Search API [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd251056.aspx) and a code sample [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd251049.aspx#Y533)

Comment: Wow, +1 for Bing. Maybe I should try using it. It'd be neat to have a search page that listed Google and Bing results side-by-side.

Comment: you won't need a page to compare them side by side, has been proved that bing is stealing results from google :DDD

Comment: @David Lively: That already exists. Here for example: http://www.blackdog.ie/google-bing/

Comment: @Davide Piras: Only the search results somebody klicks on after using IE with the Bing toolbar and agreeing to anonymously send data from using said toolbar. That makes for a rather limited subset of googles results ;-)

Comment: Thx for info about Bing didnt know that :)